# Running Vagrant provisioner with PowerShell Core 6 / PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, vagrant, powershell-core, vagrant-provision, powershell-6.0

I'd like to run PowerShell Pester tests using Vagrant on Windows Server 2008R2.

Windows Server 2008R2 has PowerShell 3.0 installed by default, and I'd obviously prefer to use a more modern version of PowerShell.

I can install PowerShell 6 using Chocolatey (e.g. `choco install powershell.portable`), but then I struggle to force the provisioner to use this version of PowerShell.

I use the [shell provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html):

```
      node.vm.provision 'invoke-tests',
        :type => 'shell',
        :path => "provisioners/invoke-tests.ps1"
```

I thought about changing the `ps1` file association from `powershell.exe` to `pwsh.exe` on a Vagrant machine in a separate provisioner that runs before the provisioner executing my tests, but I'm not sure if that would work. Also, perhaps there is an easier way of achieving it?